# Как сделать анимацию прокрутки в приложении Android

Tags: android, listview, android-animation

Я начинающий разработчик и, возможно, мой вопрос покажется глупым) Я хочу установить анимацию для ListView. Я прочитала эту документацию: [ссылка](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll)

Но понятия не имею, как это сделать. И я не могу найти ни одного примера, как это сделать. Заранее спасибо. Мне нужна такая анимация:
[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

my adapter class:

```
public class MinAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private String[] minValueList;


    public MinAdapter(Context context, String[] minValueList) {
        lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.minValueList = minValueList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return minValueList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return minValueList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


        @Override
    public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           LinearLayout cv;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        }

        TextView textMin = view.findViewById(R.id.textRow);
        textMin.setText(minValueList[position]);
        return view;
 }
}
```

my customView class:

```
public class TimView extends View {

    private String[] minList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.min);
    private ListView minListView;
    private MinAdapter minAdapter;

public TimView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TimView(Context context, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.tim_layout, viewGroup);

        minListView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.min_list);
        minAdapter = new MinAdapter(context, minList);
        minListView.setAdapter(minAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно о какой анимации идет речь? На гифке вроде обычная прокрутка?

Comment: Sergei Buvaka, анимация, которая описывается тут: https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll . С помощью методов Scroller или OverScroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю что вы имеете ввиду Bounce Effect. Такого можно добиться написав кастомный `ListView` или используя готовые библиотеки.

Как вариант можете использовать эту библиотеку
https://github.com/EverythingMe/overscroll-decor

Думаю это то что вы ищите.

Я бы посоветовал вам использовать `RecyclerView` так как он более гибкий и позволяет создавать более сложные формы отображения данных